# Google Translate C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate

I am working on a Natural Language Processing program in which I am trying to implement Google Translate. While looking for ways to implement Google translate in Assembly I came across the following code segment:

```
public static string Translate(string input, string languagePair, Encoding encoding)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=       {0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    string result = String.Empty;

    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Encoding = encoding;
        result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    }

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(result);
    return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea[@name='utrans']").InnerText;
}
```

I am relatively new to C#, I have mainly used Java, and I unclear on the implicit parameters for

```
public static string Translate(string input, string languagePair, Encoding encoding)
```

When I look in the C# API for Encoder, there were examples as to how to use the Encoding class: (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5y3703w(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
Byte[] thirdcharNoFlush = new Byte[encoder.GetByteCount(chars, 2, 1, bFlushState)];
    encoder.GetBytes(chars, 2, 1, thirdcharNoFlush, 0, bFlushState);
```

What should I input in my parameters in order to translate a phrase, such as "How are you?",  into Spanish using Google Translate. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `Translate("how are you","enes",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)`. However I don't know if you will be able to scrape the result with this snippet, as I think it pre-dates google's new UI for translate.

Comment: The keypair should be split with a "|".

Comment: @DarrenDavies I can't edit my comment any longer, but you're right

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var result = Translate("How are you?", "es|en", Encoding.UTF8);
```